# LINQ2SQL LIKE Command for Phrase

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to retrieve a list of string where it contains "Britney Spears", and this is what I use

```
from p in Objects
where p.Title.Contains("Britney Spears")
select p
```

That works fine, but if I want to select title which is "Britney Jean Spears", "Britney 'Sexy' Spears" it doesn't work, so my question is how do I insert a wildcard '%' in between Britney Spears while conducting a LINQ2SQL search? Thanks.

Regards,
Andy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) method for this purpose.

```
from p in Objects
where SqlMethods.Like(p.Title, "Britney% Spears")
select p
```

Comment: Oh that's a much nicer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `StartsWith()` and `EndsWith()` to simulate the pattern.  AFAIK, LINQ-to-SQL doesn't support wildcards.

```
from p in Objects
where p.Title.StartsWith("Britney") && c.Title.EndsWith("Spears")
select p;
```

Otherwise you could execute a query directly if you have a more complex pattern.

```
db.ExecuteQuery<MyObject>("SELECT * "
                        + "FROM Objects "
                        + "WHERE Title LIKE 'Britney%Spears'");
```

Answer (score -1):

do exactly as you would with straight up SQL

you can supply special characters with the `like` clause such as ".", "%" and "[]"

if that is not good enough, then you can use regex, but be careful since regex will be executed "client"-side, i.e. it will fetch the whole thing and then try to narrow results down in memory. You can somewhat optimize zerkms' method by doing

```
from p in Objects
where p.Title.Contains("Britney") && p.Title.Contains("Spears") && regex.Match(p.Title).Success
select p
```

I haven't tested it, but it should run first two conditions on the SQL server side, and then narrow down using regex.

Comment: This will not work with Linq2Sql; you will have to call `AsEnumerable` before applying the regex.