# Linq to SQL: Partial matching strings using contains on an array of strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, iequalitycomparer

Here is my code:

```
string[] customerNames = searchModel.CustomerName.Split(',');
 query = query.Where(d => customerNames.Contains(d.CustomerName, comparer) || customerNames.Contains(d.Company1.CompanyName, comparer));
```

Which works if you are just looking for exact matches. However I'd like to partial match, ie: if customerNames contains an element `'ell'`, it would select d if `d.CustomerName` was `'Hello'` since 'ell' is in 'Hello'

I tried overriding the EqualityComparer, but I believe it is trying to use the `GetHashCode` function rather than the `Equals` in the Comparer, which I'm not sure how to implement.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748289/linq2sql-like-command-for-phrase

Comment: GetHashCode is not guaranteed to prevent collisions so you can be sure there's more going on than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] customerNames = searchModel.CustomerName.Split(',');
query = query.Where(d => customerNames.Any(c => c.Contains(d.CustomerName)) || customerNames.Any(c => c.Contains(d.Company1.CompanyName)));
```

But you should be aware, that it may get really slow when `customerNames` has a lot of items.

Comment: I just was answering this myself. I'll check you off when 8 minutes has passed. customerNames should be very few items, but yeah I'm not sure what I can do to avoid this logic.

Comment: Will it translated to sql or will executed on client side on full set?

Comment: You can use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and just add list of `OR` conditions to your query. Which should probably be better and faster then `Any`+`Contains` chain.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Should be transform into SQL (that's why I removed the comparer).

Comment: The expression tree would be better solution in this case.

Comment: Marcin- it should actually be c => d.CustomerName.Contains(c) I believe. Might not of been obvious from how I worded the question however.