# Search From database and sort using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

In my project i have a textbox which is used for search now suppose if someone is searching hot pizza then i have to show them all result containing whether hot or pizza but i have to order them so than result containing how pizza comes first then shows result of hot and then pizza 
Currently I am Using this

```
  List<Project> allSearchedProject = new List<Project>();
  List<string> queryList = query.ToLower().Split(new char[] { '-' },                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(q => q.Length > 3).ToList();

            foreach (var q in queryList)
            {
                var matchedProjects = (from project in unitOfWork.ProjectRepository
                                      .Find(p => p.IsActive && p is Project && new[] { p.Name, p.ProjectAddress.City.Name, p.ProjectAddress.Address1 }
                                       .Any(prjt=>prjt.Contains(q)))
                                       select project as Project).AsParallel().ToList();
                allSearchedProject.AddRange(matchedProjects);
            }

            return allSearchedProject;
```

but problem is this it hits database for every word, how to do get similar result in one hit 
can anyone tell me how to search and sort in single hit

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
foreach (var q in queryList)
            {
                var matchedProjects = (from project in unitOfWork.ProjectRepository
                                      .Find(p => p.IsActive && p is Project && new[] { p.Name, p.ProjectAddress.City.Name, p.ProjectAddress.Address1 }
                                       .Any(prjt=>prjt.Contains(q)))
                                       select project as Project).AsParallel().ToList();
                allSearchedProject.AddRange(matchedProjects);
            }
```

to

```
var matchedProjects = (from project in unitOfWork.ProjectRepository
    where project.IsActive 
      && project is Project
      && (queryList.Contains(project.Name) 
         || queryList.Contains(project.ProjectAddress.City.Name)
         || queryList.Contains(project.ProjectAddress.Address1))
    select project as Project).AsParallel().ToList();
    allSearchedProject.AddRange(matchedProjects);
```

Edit: removed projection and made contains searching explicit for fields on project being searched

Comment: didn't get this Line .Any(queryList.Contains(prjt=>prjt))
and it has compile error too.

Comment: Sorry, just realised a mistake in the `.Any` lambda, which is now corrected.

Comment: thanks i have corrected it but it is not working do i have to convert it in ToLower()

Comment: Edit made, now that I can see shape of data you were projecting into. Note projection part removed from `Find`

Comment: it's working fine but in Sql it search like 
(([Filter1].[Name1] IN (N'vishal')) AND ([Filter1].[Name1] IS NOT NULL))
but what i need is (([Filter1].[Name1] Like (N'%vishal%')) AND ([Filter1].[Name1] IS NOT NULL))

Comment: That is a different question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748289/linq2sql-like-command-for-phrase leads to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx

Comment: .net doesn't support LIKE in LINQ to entities.
see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5877ea99-cf4a-470b-ad99-54ff9893b490/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean-likestring?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60875/discussion-between-vishal-pandey-and-mashton).